# Gets duplicated mapping key error using openapi 3.0

Tags: yaml, openapi, swagger-3.0

I am trying to define my APIs using `openapi` version `3.0.0`. I've generated following YAML file:

```
openapi: 3.0.0

info:
    title: My YAML
    description: My YAML
    version: 1.0.0

servers:
- url: http://my.server.url

paths:
     /v1/service/uri:
        post:
          summary: Getting some information.
          parameters:

          - name: Content-Type
            in: header
            description: Content type of request body.
            required: true
            style: simple
            explode: false
            schema:
              type: string

          - name: Host 
            in: header
            description: Originate host which returns the response.
            required: false
            style: simple
            explode: false
            schema:
              type: string

          requestBody:
            content:
              application/json:
                schema:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/MyPostRequest'
                  example:
                      my_name: "zizi"
                      my_age: 29

            required: true

          responses:
            200:
              description: OK
                  content:
                    application/json:
                      schema:
                        $ref: '#/components/schemas/MyPostResponse'

components:
    schemas:

        MyPostRequest:
            type: object
            properties:
                my_name:
                    type: string
                my_age:
                    type: integer
                    format: int32

        MyPostResponse:
            type: object
            properties:
                status:
                    type: integer
                    format: int32
```

When I copy/paste these lines into [Swagger Editor](https://editor.swagger.io/), it gives me `duplicated mapping key` error on line `19`; it is for section `description` of parameter `Content-Type`.

I have studied [openapi documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/), but I didn't see anything wrong with my YAML file.

Comment: In addition to Anthon's answer - you also need to remove the `Content-Type` and `Host` parameters. The `Content-Type` of the request is inferred from `requestBody.content.<content-type>` and `Host` is inferred from `servers`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure why you get that error, I tried to find out in which language Swagger is written, as there are several YAML parsers out there that are known to have problems, but couldn't easily determine that using google or wikipedia.

You don't have any duplicate keys in your file, but it is invalid (i.e. not valid YAML) because of the indentation of the key `content` (the second occurrence, the one under `paths` →
`/v1/service/uri` → `post` → `responses` → `200`), that should be aligned with 
`description` as that key cannot have a value node that is both a scalar (`OK`) as well as a mapping node `content: ....`

Comment: You were right. The indentation problem has happened because of mixing tabs and spaces in multiple editors. I didn't notice that at first place.

Comment: so "duplicated mapped key" parser error might indicate an indent error. Thanks, +1 from me.